# Laravel elixir version looking in the build directory incorrectly

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel Elixir (5.2) to do some gulp tasks such as concatenating files and then versioning them.

When I version them, by default, they output into the '/build' directory in my public folder. I don't want this to happen- I want them up one level without the build folder.

Looking at the source code for Elixir, I could see that you could pass a directory as another parameter to the `version` method and the files would be created there.

However, when you try and run your application, it throws an exception as it is looking for the manifest in the build directory.

Line 295 of `laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php` has the following function, which is called in the blade template to get the path for the filename of the versioned file:

```
function elixir($file)
{
    static $manifest = null;

    if (is_null($manifest)) {
        $manifest = json_decode(file_get_contents(public_path('build/rev-manifest.json')), true);
    }

    if (isset($manifest[$file])) {
        return '/build/'.$manifest[$file];
    }

    throw new InvalidArgumentException("File {$file} not defined in asset manifest.");
}
```

I can fix my issue by removing the hardcoding of the build directory.
2 questions:
1. Is this a bug with Laravel?
2. Is it normal to put public assets into a 'build' directory?

Comment: Having the exact same issue... looks like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

You have to have both assets and rev-manifest in the build folder, in order to use `elixir` helper method.
Even if you create `rev-manifest.json` with correct paths and store it in build/ so elixir can get to it, it will still create paths to the assets with *build/* prefix.

I ended up creating my own helper function to resolve paths from the root folder (basically the same code, without hard coded build/ part)